# Инициализация массива std::array структурами

Tags: c++

Хотел вот так инициализировать массив:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct r{
        std::string name;
        int x;
};

int main()
{
        std::array<r, 2> a { {"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2} };
}
```

Но выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:50: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<r, 2>’
   12 |  std::array<r, 2> a { {"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2} };
      |                                                  ^
```

Если я добавлю следующим образом еще одни скобки, то все будет ок:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct r{
        std::string name;
        int x;
};

int main()
{
        std::array<r, 2> a {{ {"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2} }};
}
```

Вопрос: для чего нужны эти дополнительные скобки? Ведь по логике в первом варианте внешние - это uniform-инициализация, а внутренние - обозначения каждой отдельной структуры и все должно работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array<T, N>` - это класс, с одним публичным полем вида `T некоторое_имя[N];` (по крайней мере для `N > 0`).

Поэтому, в `std::array<r, 2> a {{ {"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2} }};`, внешние скобки - для всего класса `std::array`, следующие скобки - для этого массива, и две пары внутренних скобок - для элементов этого массива.

---

Интереснее другое. Почему `std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};` работает с одной парой скобок?

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) говорит вот что:

> The braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to initialize the following members of the object.

Говоря простым языком, убирать скобки можно только начиная с самых вложенных скобок.

Пример: если у нас есть

```
std::array<r, 2> a{{{"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2}}};
```

То первым шагом мы можем убрать только самые вложенные пары скобок. Получаем:

```
std::array<r, 2> a{{"weklrj", 3, "lekw", 2}};
```

Дальше мы снова можем убрать самые вложенные скобки:

```
std::array<r, 2> a{"weklrj", 3, "lekw", 2};
```

Но, конечно, такое убирание скобок работает только если в середине не пропущены инициализаторы. Например, `std::array<r, 2> a{{ {"weklrj"}, {"lekw"} }};` компилируется, а `std::array<r, 2> a{{"weklrj", "lekw"}};` уже нет, потому что компилятор будет пытаться преобразовать вторую строку к `int`у.

Comment: Интересно, что для случая `{"weklrj", 3, "lekw", 2};` clang предлагает (через warning) поставить скобки вокруг подобъектов. Но если это сделать, то получим исходную ошибку и придётся ещё самые внешние скобки добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы пишите

```
{ "строка", 3 }
```

вы инициализируете структуру, а конкретней присваиваете её полям `name` и `x` значения `"строка"` и `3`.

Когда же вы пишите:

```
array<r,2> a { элемент1, элемент2 }
```

Это выглядит таким образом: у структуры `array` как будто есть 2 поля, которые вы инициализируете `элемент1` и `элемент2`, что не является правдой.

В исходном коде структуры `array` есть такая строчка:

```
value_type _M_instance[_Nm ? _Nm : 1];
```

где `value_type` это в вашем случае структура `r`, `_Nm` это размер `2`. То есть вы добавляя `{}` просто инициализируете этот массив.

Answer (score 0):

Массив `std :: array` реализован как структура. У него есть только два конструктора. По умолчанию и фактического.

```
array<type,n> a;
array<type,n> a = { x , y } ;
```

Много фигурных скобок затрудняют компилятору определить представленные типы автоматически. Запись с фактическим типом `r`

```
std::array<r, 2> a { r {"weklrj", 3},  r {"lekw", 2} };
```

помогает компилятору определить тип `r` и он вызывает конструктор "aggregate-инициализации".

А также вызов конструктора с одним аргументом

```
std::array<r, 2> a { { {"weklrj", 3},  {"lekw", 2} } } ;
```

автоматически даёт один путь к вызову конструктора "aggregate-инициализации".

Вызов конструктора  с элементами из структур неуказанного типа

```
std::array<r, 2> a { {"weklrj", 3}, {"lekw", 2} };
```

приводит к неопределённости : если это нужно делать "aggregate-инициализацию", то аргументов слишком много. А так как перед фигурными скобками не указан тип, то определить, что это структура `r` или другая невозможно.

Comment: *"вызов конструктора с двумя аргументами"* Если так, то почему `std::array<int, 2> arr{1, 2};` работает?

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что в последних двух случаях будет перемещение. Судя по [вот этому](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), и там и там должна быть просто aggregate-инициализация.

Comment: Что связано с автоматическим определением типа : или структура или массив ? С Интом вроде бы автоматика распознала. Надо подумать.  @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Переписал, скорее всего это много скобок вводит в стоп компилятор. @HolyBlackCat